# Why does Foundation use margin-left: 1.25rem for <ul>

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

```
 ul {
     margin-left: 1.25rem;
     list-style-type: disc; }
```

Foundation uses % for margin-left and margin-right.

However on unordered list they use rem for margin-left.

I'm having trouble understanding the logic behind this.

Comment: This was a fun read today. Thank you! The thinking is probably that 'ul' relates to text and they use rem for textual elements, percentages for block elements. Just a guess.

Answer (score 3):

Rems are similar to % and em as they are fractionally based off of the base font size (default 16px). Unlike % and em, rem units do not inherit a parent element's font size. With % and em, as you nest elements, you'll see the font size get smaller and smaller. This doesn't happen with rem units. Instead, no matter where in the DOM hierarchy an element is, a rem-sized element always references the base font size.

Using rem for the margin and padding that surrounds text elements provides scalability within a layout. padding: 10rem; @ 16px base font size yields 160px of padding. changing the base font size would not only scale the font size up or down, it would change surrounding elements that use rem units proportionally. Foundation also uses rem for media queries. The idea is, if you increased the base font size, not only would font sizes get bigger and containers would grow, breakpoints would be triggered sooner.

Answer (score 0):

Percentages are used mostly on the grid because those scales perfectly; the left margin of lists generates the indentation of the list, which is text-related design rhythm, so using the base font size (rem) is quite logical (to me).